# Get count of identical values in keys

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary in python as below it contains different users as U who has bought products as P.
Need to find out how many users have bought same set of products :

dict = {'U1':['P1','P2','P3'],'U2':['P5','P1'],'U3':['P1','P3','P2'],'U4':['P7','P6'],'U5':['P1','P5'],'U6':['P1','P2','P3']}

So above is input :

Output will be :
3 users bought ['P1','P2','P3']
2 users bought ['P5','P1']
1 users bought ['P7','P6']`enter code here`

## below i tried but it does not return wht i want:

Comment: [List comparison](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-check-if-two-lists-are-identical/) will be help-full to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `frozenset` and `Counter` might be the easiest way.

```
from collections import Counter

data = {'U1':['P1','P2','P3'],'U2':['P5','P1'],'U3':['P1','P3','P2'],'U4':['P7','P6'],'U5':['P1','P5'],'U6':['P1','P2','P3']}

c = Counter(frozenset(x) for x in list(data.values()))
print(c)
# Counter({frozenset({'P1', 'P3', 'P2'}): 3, frozenset({'P5', 'P1'}): 2, frozenset({'P7', 'P6'}): 1})
```